# Reset countdown timer in Android when switching between activities

Tags: android

Here I have 3 activities: A, B, and C. From Activity A When I click a button it will goes to Activity B. When Activity B loads the countdown timer will start. Again, when I click a button in Activity B it will go to Activity C. Here I Need a Help.

1. When Activity C starts I need the countdown timer from Activity B to resume.
2. Again I switch over from Activity C to Activity B the countdown timer should be resumed from Activity C.

### Activity A

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         addListenerOnButton();


    }



    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actone);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Act_Two.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   
            }
        });
     }
}
```

### Activity B

```
  public class Act_Two extends Activity{
    Button button;
    public TextView textView1;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_two);
        textView1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        MyCount counter = new MyCount(61000,1000);
        counter.start();
        addListenerOnButton();

}
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.acttwo);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Act_Three.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   


            }

        });
}

   public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

    //iFallApp app1 = new iFallApp();

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //textView1.setText("done");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        textView1.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should pass the count timer value on activity start through intent  using Intent.putInt(value);

Comment: @Ramya. Some code was deleted from the question (probably by mistake because of overlapping edits). You put it back. Fair enough: good job. But why on earth did you use the edit summary *improved formatting*? What sense it that supposed to make?

Comment: @TRiG ya ok i understood..sorry for my mistakes.. here after i won't do like this..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While switching between the activities, try to pass the current count down time with the help of Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You should save a value of your `CountDownTimer` in Activty B and stop the `CountDownTimer` (using the `cancel()` method) in Activty B's `onPause` and start that `CountDownTimer` with saved value in `onResume` of Activty B. something like (assuming this is an Activity B code):

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // turning off the timer
    isWihesCountUpdateTimerNeeded = false;
    if (wihesCountUpdateTimer!=null)
        wihesCountUpdateTimer.cancel();

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // resuming the timer 
    isWihesCountUpdateTimerNeeded = true;
    totalWishesCount = SharedPrefsHelper.getTotalWishesCount(getActivity());
    startWihesCountUpdateTimer();
}

    // the timer increases some wishes count
private boolean isWihesCountUpdateTimerNeeded;
private CountDownTimer wihesCountUpdateTimer;
protected static final int wihesCountUpdateTimerDuration=5000;
protected int totalWishesCount;
private void startWihesCountUpdateTimer() {
    wihesCountUpdateTimer = null;
    if (!isWihesCountUpdateTimerNeeded)
        return;
    final int duration = wihesCountUpdateTimerDuration;
    //Log.i(this, "startWihesCountUpdateTimer() duration: "+duration);
    wihesCountUpdateTimer = new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            totalWishesCount++; 
            SharedPrefsHelper.saveTotalWishesCount(getActivity(), totalWishesCount);
            startWihesCountUpdateTimer();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Can u please explain me in detail

Comment: In My question I didn't attach my Full Code ...Here I Attach My Code

Comment: Use EDIT of your question to edit/add something instead of answering your own question. However my src is clear to understand and you should implement it for your needs by yourself.

Comment: Okay Stan Will follow ur source